# Confirmation message repeats in every iteration

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, tkinter

I'm making a simple GUI with Tkinter.
Basically you point to a directory and if the directory has folders ending in ".WAV", he loops through every folder and deletes the ".WAV" suffix.

I want it to end the loop and then show a confirmation message, but with the current code the program shows a message per folder renamed, making the user hit "OK" on every folder.

```
def execute():
directory = entry.get()

for folder in os.listdir(directory):
    if folder.endswith(".WAV"):
        os.rename(os.path.join(directory, folder), os.path.join(directory, folder[:-4]))
        messagebox.showinfo("All folders renamed successfully!", "All folders were renamed successfully!")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error renaming folders!", 'Make sure there's only folders ending in ".WAV" in the selected directory.')
        break
```

Comment: "The code in my loop happens during every loop" - The simple answer is to move the code you only want to happen at the end to after the loop.

Comment: @user1558604 OK, it solved my problem but now when I don't have any folders ending in ".WAV", he shows me the error and the shows me the confirmation, ignoring the break

Comment: What I would do is start an empty list. If I ran into a folder without `.wav`, I would append that folder name to the list. After the loop, I would use an if statement. If the length of that list is >0, show the error (maybe even include the list of folders that caused the error), else, show confirmation. That way you don't have to break, and you can do all the files except for the ones that don't have `.wav`. But I don't know your use case, so that might not work.

Comment: The other alternative would be to put the whole loop and the confirmation message in a try block, and rather than using `break`, raise an exception, that you then catch and show the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: end the loop and then show a confirmation message

```
def execute():
    directory = entry.get()

    ok = None        
    for folder in os.listdir(directory):
        if folder.endswith(".WAV"):
            os.rename(os.path.join(directory, folder), os.path.join(directory, folder[:-4]))
            ok = True
        else:
            ok = False
            break

    if ok
        messagebox.showinfo("All folders renamed successfully!", "All folders were renamed successfully!")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error renaming folders!", 'Make sure there's only folders ending in ".WAV" in the selected directory.')
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you added some explanatory text. Otherwise we have to read line-by-line and character-by-character to see what you did differently.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have changed to **comiunity wiki**, feel free to add ***"some explanatory text"***.

Comment: I don't want to have to try to understand your answer enough to do that (and that's the point). I'm just trying to let you know that your answer isn't as obvious as you might think. Code-only answers are discouraged on this site.